# How do you keep numeric values when importing SPSS to Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spss

I've imported an SPSS document to Pandas, however, when doing so it seems to turn all numeric values into text values, using the variable label instead of the numeric data in the SPSS dataset.

For instance, the below image shows the first bunch of values for the variable Processing_1 in the dataset.

[First rows of var in SPSS dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uOcx.png)

These numeric values have labels in SPSS that match to descriptive text (it's actually a 1-5 scale from Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree).

I used the following code to import this into Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import os, sys, pyreadstat

df = pd.read_spss("URL")

vtf = "Processing_1"
for ind in range(10):
    print(df[vtf][ind])
```

This produces the output of:

```
Strongly agree
Neither agree nor disagree
Neither agree nor disagree
Strongly agree
Strongly agree
Disagree
Strongly disagree
Disagree
Strongly agree
Neither agree nor disagree
```

So it's converting them to the labels. When I then export from Pandas back to SPSS...

```
pyreadstat.write_sav(df, 'DATASET N')
```

...and open the SPSS dataset, I now see all those variables as string variables with no numeric values.

How do I ensure that they are still numric in Pandas/after I export from Pandas back to SPSS?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing `pyreadstat`anyway, you might as well use it to read the data which should reutrn
a) a pd.DataFrame object containing the values
b) a meta object containing the meta-information of the dataset (labels and some such)

Using

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav("URL")
```

Should give you the two objects described.

See https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html for the documentation